# Trouble install MySQL 8 to Debian 10

Tags: mysql, linux, debian

I tried to install MySQL 0.8.16-1 to a Debian 10 system.
I followed this description:

https://serverspace.io/support/help/how-to-install-mysql-on-debian-10/
These are the commands I ran:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install gnupg

cd /tmp

wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mysql-community-server
```

At the end of the installation I always get the following in the log:

```
emitting matrix      : 100% |###########################################|  
done!
    update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8 to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
    Setting up mysql-community-client (8.0.22-1debian10) ...
    Setting up mysql-client (8.0.22-1debian10) ...
    Setting up mysql-community-server (8.0.22-1debian10) ...
    update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
    my_print_defaults: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
    my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
    my_print_defaults: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
    my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
    my_print_defaults: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
    my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
    my_print_defaults: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
    my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
    mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
    mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
    dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
     installed mysql-community-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     mysql-community-server
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've already tried completely remove MySQL and reinstall. After purge, autoremove and autoclean ran the:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and ran the install again but didn't help.

I checked the directory /etc/mysql but it looks like ok for me:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jan  7 07:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 73 root root 4096 Jan  7 07:46 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   24 Jan  7 07:46 my.cnf -> /etc/alternatives/my.cnf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1497 Sep 23 09:40 mysql.cnf
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan  7 07:46 mysql.conf.d
```

Any suggestion what cause this issue?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get purge mysql-community-server`, then remove your whole mysql folder manually `sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql`, then reinstall `sudo apt-get install -y mysql-community-server`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Frank. Unfortunately it didn't help. I did what you wrote and got the same problem:   

`Setting up mysql-community-server (8.0.22-1debian10) ... update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode my_print_defaults: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)`  

I checked mysql folder created, with the file:  
`lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   24 Jan 11 02:36 my.cnf -> /etc/alternatives/my.cnf`  
`-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1497 Sep 23 09:40 mysql.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the VPS server had only 0.5 gb RAM.
For MySQL 8.0.. minimum 4 gb is recommended!
I know this is a stupid mistake but maybe someone can learn from this.